# What real EIP-1559 base fee on polygon chain?

Tags: polygon, eip-1559

When I call the `fee_history` method from the [web3 library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py), the `polygon` node returns a non-null [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559) base fee.

Request on `eth_feeHistory` returns response:

```py
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 0, 'result': {'baseFeePerGas': ['0x22', '0x23', '0x27', '0x2b', '0x30'], 'gasUsedRatio': [0.5150423384224325, 0.9958615949232461, 0.9957990374455649, 0.9990101827216755], 'oldestBlock': '0x17e3f8c', 'reward': [['0x8c063bbc9', '0x1202ddc65e', '0x174876e7de'], ['0x80ccb79cd', '0xba43b7400', '0x15896dfcef'], ['0x72ffed179', '0x730fe0971', '0x9502f8fd9'], ['0x7fc7076e6', '0x7fc7076e6', '0x8ddbeaff0']]}}
```

We see that the base fee is equal to `[34, 35, 39, 43, 48]`. It's on [infura](https://infura.io).
But local node returns 22 Wei as the base fee for the next block.

However, on https://polygonscan.com/gastracker and https://polygonscan.com/blocks I see blocks with a base fee close to 0 Gwei (ex. 13 Wei: https://polygonscan.com/block/25035822) and blocks with a base fee of tens of Gwei (ex. 68 Gwei: https://polygonscan.com/block/25013644).

What is the real base fee on polygon chain, close zero Gwei or not?
Is the formula for calculating the max fee in the form of `(base fee + max priority fee)` relevant?
And why does a local node always return 22 Wei as the base fee?

Answer (score 0):

The formula for calculating the maximum fee in the form of (base fee + max priority fee) is relevant, as this is the maximum fee that a user can pay for a transaction. However, the actual fee paid by a transaction depends on the current network conditions, and it may be less than the maximum fee.

The reason why your local node always returns 22 Wei as the base fee may be due to a configuration issue or the node may not be fully synchronized with the network. It's always a good practice to check multiple sources of information, such as Etherscan and other block explorers, to get a better understanding of the current network conditions.